# Remotely programmatically manage IIS 6 and later

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7, iis-6, automation

I have been trying to figure out how I would be able to write an application to deploy IIS configs to multiple WebServers.  The web configurations will be taken from one environment and then be restored on one or more webservers.  I have tried out the DirectroyServices API from .NET to manage IIS.  I wanted to export all the configurations and the import them into another physical WebServer running the same version of IIS.  The virtual directories where restored, but not all of its parameters were allowed.  For example security properties with passwords that are set.

From what I found looking around it looks like the DirectoryServices API for IIS doesn’t implement all the features you need.  I was able to Shell out AppCMD from my application.  What I didn’t like about this is that I had to use a Remote Execution tool so remotely execute a batch script which takes care of the Restore and Backup of IIS.

Is there a better way to do this?  I was looking into PowerShell to see if I can write a script to do what I need, but was wondering if that same script can also work for IIS 6 and IIS 7?

Thanks in advance for any input!

Comment: Can you expand on what versions of IIS are you copying the configuration from/to? e.g. `IIS6 -> IIS6`, `IIS6 -> IIS7`, `IIS7 -> IIS7`

Comment: At the very least it should copy the configs from the same IIS version to the same IIS version.  If it copies the configs to a different IIS version, then configs that match should be updated, and any config that did not get updated should be logged.

Answer (score 1):

Deploy and Migration is very easy with Microsoft Web Deploy: http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy

I am currently using this synchronize web application files, IIS settings and ACL settings between IIS6 and IIS7 boxes.

Comment: Hi Markis, thanks for your response.  I saw this tool before.  It looked like a individual application which runs on its own for deployment.  If it has a API available to access it programmatically then it’s possible that I would be able to use it.  I am hoping not to have to install this tool on the client machines, and just reference any assemblies it has.

Comment: Not an API per se, but everything is done by command line arguments.  So you could do everything from a power shell script.

Comment: This will copy everything between boxes:

msdeploy -verb:sync -source:metakey=lm/w3svc,computername=REMOTE_COMPUTER_NAME_HERE -dest:metakey=lm/w3svc